# Haskell : runGetState and lists

Tags: parsing, haskell, binary

Hello I am trying to write a simple binary parser in Haskell using the runGetState monad.

However, I am faced with the problem of parsing a list of fields and I am stuck.

The problem is that the list of fields can change from time to time thus I want to construct the list fields and then read them in using a map. Code snippet below:

```
readField field_type =

            case (field_type) of
              0   -> A1 <$> getWord8
              132 -> A2 <$> getWord16be
              134 -> A3 <$> getWord32be

parseData fields =  return $ map (\x -> readField x) a

(fdata,input,no) <- return (runGetState (parseData [132,134,0]) input no)
```

I tried the above solution without luck. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please let us know what the problem is.  Is there an error?  Not expected output?  Just to help us guide what we are looking for without having to actually compile and run the code ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it should be something like

```
parseData = mapM readField
```

Comment: Bugger me. I just tried precisely what you wrote and it works! Thanks @augustss.